# adjusting easy python code "adding small condition"

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, python-3.9

I was trying to adjust this code so it accepts if I wrote rock , paper or scissor in small or capital letter. and if it wasn't one of these three words then it should exit the program and print "WRITE IT CORRECTLY!")

```
import random
y = input("Enter rock, paper or scissor: ")
x = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
z = random.choice(x)
c = print("Computer: " + str(z) )


if (y=="rock" and z=="scissor"):
    print("YOU WON!")

elif  (y=="rock" and z=="paper"):
    print("COMPUTER WON!")

elif  (y=="rock" and z=="rock"):
    print("TRY AGAIN!")

elif  (y=="paper" and z=="rock"):
      print("YOU WON!")

elif (y=="paper" and z=="paper"):
    print("TRY AGAIN!")

elif (y=="paper" and z=="scissor"):
    print("COMPUTER WON!")

elif (y=="scissor" and z=="rock"):
    print("COMPUTER WON!")
```

Comment: You can just convert the input string in lower case before proceeding i.e.                                  `y = input("Enter rock, paper or scissor: ").lower()`

Comment: Okay, cool. Do you have a question? Please read [ask].

Comment: Please don't edit your question into something completely different, that makes all comments and answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
y = y.lower()
```

This will change everything in the input to lowercase and helps you with the program!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of the user input after you receive it.

```
y = input("Enter rock, paper or scissor: ")
if y.lower() not in ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]:
    print("WRITE IT CORRECTLY!)
```

Put this in a loop to repeat until you receive an expected value, then continue on with the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = input("Enter rock, paper or scissor: ").lower()

if y not in x:

    print("Write it correctly!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another “if” to check for the input value before .

```
if y not in x:
   print ("WRITE IT CORRECTLY!")
else:
   #continue with current code
```